# How to run php script from CLI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the method stored in `Z:\work\project\apps\controllers\_cron\tools\method`

How can I call "method" using the command line?

Comment: If you mean `method` literally as in method of a class, you will need a script that calls this method and then run this script from CLI.

Comment: @fab: One could do `-r "include(...); my_method();"` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You run the PHP executable with the location of the file as an argument (Windows example: `php.exe path/to/method.php`). The location of `php.exe` depends on where you installed it.

**[Read more.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)**

Comment: I use the methot presentated here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html, but the response is index page in html(main page).                                                           $ php index.php tools method

Answer (score 1):

Easy as

`C:\path\to\php.exe -f "Z:\path\to\file.php"`

Source:
[#1 result for "run php from command line windows" in google](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php)